# How to set order of Grouping Field in Format Settings

Tags: 7, views

I'm on D7. I have a taxonomy "projects". A project can be "ongoing" or "completed. I currently have a view that get's all projects (projects are a taxonomy/vocabulary). The "ongoing" and "completed" are project types which are also a taxonomy/vocabulary.

In the view, I set Grouping field Nr.1 to Taxonomy Term: Project Type

I want to make sure that "ongoing" is above "completed". How can I do that? Somehow the order changed from "ongoing, completed" to "completed, ongoign" after I updated an ongoing project to completed.

The order of the taxonomy terms seem to not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can set the weight of the Project Type terms in the vocabulary.

Then you have to create the following relationship:

> Entity Reference: Referenced Entity
>
> A bridge to the Taxonomy term entity that is referenced via field_project_type

Then, add a Sort Criterion (first) Taxonomy term: Weight using the above relationship.

Comment: How do I sort by "Project Type Term Weight"? I currently have this: https://imgur.com/a/HVafi

Comment: actually I don't have a content-type "projects", just ataxonomy "projects".

Comment: You have to create a Relationship to your project type field first, in case you haven't done it yet. I am updating my answer.

Comment: I don't have "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" in Relationships. I do have e.g. " Taxonomy term: Project Type (field_project_type)", do you mean that? Edit: I got it working using that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will probably work as well.